# prestashop home category showing 404 error page

Tags: prestashop-1.6

In prestashop-1.6.1.5 after some code fixing the home category disappeared.

```php
<?php

class CategoryController extends CategoryControllerCore
{
    public function canonicalRedirection($canonicalURL = '')
    {
        if (Tools::getValue('live_edit'))
            return ;
        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($this->category) || 
!$this->category->inShop() || !$this->category->isAssociatedToShop() || 
$this->category->id == Configuration::get('PS_ROOT_CATEGORY'))
        {
            $this->redirect_after = '404';
            $this->redirect();
        }
        if (!Tools::getValue('noredirect') &&
 Validate::isLoadedObject($this->category))
            FrontController::canonicalRedirection(
$this->context->link->getCategoryLink($this->category));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code issue is fixed

Comment: Now home category is not showing 404 error working properly but in the dashboard that is back office catalog->categories I am getting all the sub categories under home but not able to get the home category tab..                  So please guide me how to get the home tab in back office that is admin panel